# Execute JS Script in WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I want execute JavaScript in my WebView for remove a element in html.

It's my class :

```
private void WebViewProfil (){
        String url = "http://google.com/XXX";
        final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview52);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                String javaScript ="javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top')[0].style.display='none'";
                webview.loadUrl(javaScript);
                Log.d("[WV]", " JS OK");
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        Log.d("[WV]", " WEB OK");
    }
```

Webview is loading correctly but when the JS code is execute, i see "none" in my WebView.

Why that's not remove the element from webpage ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String javaScript ="javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top')[0].style.display='none';void(0);";

You need to add `void(0)` at the end of the script